# How to save data from axios.get to hooks right away

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How will I able to save in hooks that data from database. Since I need to display the data that I get to dropdown.

Here's my code

```
const [dataSystem, setdataSystem] = useState([])
const getAllSystems = async() => {
  ......
}

const getDependentSystems = async() => {
  const response = await axios.get('/API' + ID)
  console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)
  setdataSystem(response.data)
}
```

Since upon `setState`, data is not yet saved to `dataSystem` I need to trigger `getDeoendetSystems()` twice to display the list on my dropdown.

Result of `console.log`

```
LIST OF SYSTEM [{...},{...}]
  0: {ID: 1, SYSTEMID: 12 ...},
  1: {ID: 2, SYSTEMID: 13 ...}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the data inside an `useEffect` like

```
function Component() {
    
  const [dataSystem, setdataSystem] = useState([])
  
  useEffect(() => {
  
   getDependentSystems()

  }, [])
  
  const getDependentSystems = async() => {
    const response = await axios.get('/API' + ID)
    console.log('LIST OF SYSTEM', response.data)
    setdataSystem(response.data)
  }
  
  
return ...
}
```

Basically you want to call the function in the `useEffect` so you only call it once; cause if you call it in the component context, everytime the state updates it will call the api again which will trigger an infinite loop.

Comment: since you are using effect it's best not use async/await, instead use a promisse.

Comment: @guilhermevictorramalhonatal why is that? there shouldn't be an issue with the example above. The async/await is used in the `getDependentSystems` and useEffect only need to call it when its first loaded, it doesnt need to wait for the data, the state will be change when the api returns :-/

Comment: Async/await are blocking, so if you need load anything else it will wait the request while promisses can run in parallel

Comment: Hi @constantin chirila my apologies, I was not able to include in the questiom that i need to click a button to call `getdependentsystems` so the id is based on the selected system in the table row. Hope you can help me with this

Comment: @JayDee Just just make `getDependentSystems` to accept a prop called ID like `const getDependentSystems = async (id) => { }` and use the id in the logic of the function, thn just call that function on the `onClick` handler fo the row. Hopefully this makes sense. Sorry for the late reply, was on holiday :)

Comment: @guilhermevictorramalhonatal  im pretty sure, that the async/await will block only inside the scope of the async function. It will not stop the function from rendering while the request is happening. Thats why a function is called asynchronous, because it will trigger that function and move on, only whats happening inside the function after each await it will block the stack hence the wait in the `await` :D

Comment: @ConstantinChirila, JS is single-threaded (it can run only 1 thing at time, in this case the async function) if your render depends on the result of an async function, it will not render until the function is complete. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await